# How do I use display style in running text?

Tags: math-mode, displaystyle

I'm writing my thesis. Problem is that when I type the following mathematical expressions inside the equation environment and outside it, I get a different style of the same mathematical expressions:

```
A population $N(t)$ is said to be persist (or strongly persist) 
if $N(0)> 0$ implies $N(t) > 0$ and $\liminf_{t\to\infty}{N(t)} > 0$
```

or

```
\begin{equation*} 
\liminf_{t\to\infty}{N(t)} > 0 
\end{equation*}.
```

Why does the command `\liminf_{t\to\infty}` look differently in each case? I need to use both version i.e. in text and inside equation. But I want it to look same everywhere.

Comment: No you don't `\liminf` looks like that in text mode as if it was typeset in display mode form, then it would disturb the line spacing. It is tradition to place the limit as a subscripts in textstyle math.

Answer (score 1):

You asked,

> Why does the command \liminf_{t\to\infty} look differently in each case?

What you have "discovered" is that inline-math and display-math typesetting conventions differ in several ways. This difference is *not* a problem. Instead, it is a typesetting convention that has evolved and stood the test of time over decades (centuries?) of typesetting practice.

If you absolutely feel like you have to override TeX's default settings for typesetting inline math material, you may do so quite easily, by inserting `\displaystyle` directives after initiating inline math mode.

Just be prepared to have to accept inferior typographic results, as the line spacing within a paragraph will look highly uneven. To wit, compare the two three-line paragraphs in the following screenshot. In the first paragraph, the distance between lines 1 and 2 is the same as between lines 2 and 3. This is decidedly *not* the case in the second paragraph, which employs two `\displaystyle` directives. I'm fully aware of the saying that there's no arguing about tastes. Nevertheless, I would posit that the first paragraph is superior, typographically speaking, to the second.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\hrule 
A population $N(t)$ is said to be persist (or strongly persist) 
if $N(0)> 0$ implies $N(t) > 0$ and $\liminf_{t\to\infty}{N(t)} > 0$.
A population $N(t)$ is said to be persist (or strongly persist) 
if $N(0)> 0$ implies $N(t) > 0$ and $\liminf_{t\to\infty}{N(t)} > 0$.
\hrule
A population $N(t)$ is said to be persist (or strongly persist) 
if $N(0)> 0$ implies $N(t) > 0$ and $\displaystyle\liminf_{t\to\infty}{N(t)} > 0$.
A population $N(t)$ is said to be persist (or strongly persist) 
if $N(0)> 0$ implies $N(t) > 0$ and $\displaystyle\liminf_{t\to\infty}{N(t)} > 0$.
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Comment: Inserting \displaystyle directives after initiating inline math mode, gives me the result I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @RameshwarPrasadMishra - Please keep in mind that just because it is *possible* to do something in no way implies that it's a good idea to do it.

Comment: Dear @Mico, I understand your concern, and I really appreciate your suggestion. But here I can't apply your suggestion because I must follow my supervisor's advice. Thank you again for your kind help and suggestions.

Comment: @RameshwarPrasadMishra - Ah yes, the well-known "my advisor is clueless but I must follow his/her advice"... reason. Well, a binding constraint is a binding constraint. I will hope, for your sake, that once you are no longer forced to heed this type of inferior advice, you'll seize the opportunity to optimize over a broader parameter space. :-)

Comment: Definitely, I'll do.